# testing devise CustomFailure App with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I have used a custom devise failure app.

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp
protected
    def redirect_url
        LOGIN_URL
    end
```

end

I make use of default failure app and custom failure app based on environment variable.

I want to test this functionality with rspec. Here is what I want to do in rspec

```
If env['var'] = value
    expect redirect_url to return 'hostname/customlogin/'
else
    expect redirect_url to return 'hostname/sign_in/'
```

But problem is that CustomeFailure app will exist only when I have set env['var'].

```
if ENV["var"] == value
    config.warden do |manager|
        manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
    end
end
```

So how I can test this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write test case for this scenario. It is not the correct behavior that I want but I can continue with this.

```
require 'rails_helper'
describe CustomFailure do
    describe '.redirect_url' do
        let(:expected_result) { 'hostname/customlogin' }
        it 'returns the login url' do
            @custom = CustomFailure.new
            expect(@custom.send(:redirect_url)).to eq(expected_result)
        end
    end
end
```